# CSS circle profile photo - bad quality

Tags: html, css

I have an issue regarding the user's profile photo. The photo is the following: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrBAT.png)

On sites like YouTube the photo quality is better than on my site: [example on YouTube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnjY3.png)

On my site the image has a very low quality: [example on my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vG5s.png)

HTML:

```
<div class="profile-photo">
   <img src="profile-photo/1.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.profile-photo {
  width: 2.8rem;
  height: 2.8rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this photo quality issue? Thank you.

Comment: Take a higher quality photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're taking a 644px image and shrinking it down to, what, 40px - 6% of its original height? That's going to cause some distortion.

The profile image in the corner in YouTube is 88px x 88px, so shrinking that down to 32x32 (25%) is going to look much better.

@Justinas' suggestion is about all you can do with just CSS.  However, if you have control over the whole system, consider creating a smaller version of whatever image the user uploads.  Not only will it create a crisper image, but the viewer won't have to download the full image when they just want an icon.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to actually reduce size of your image to ~match size of wrapper
2. Try adding `image-rendering: crisp-edges;`[[1]](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/) to your image.
3. Sometimes `transform: translateZ(0);` helps too.
4. Inspect actual image in Youtube to see any other properties applied for better quality.

```css
.profile-photo {
  width: 2.8rem;
  height: 2.8rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.profile-photo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-photo">
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrBAT.png">
</div>
```